# Adding a subview of one xib file to another xib file in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, subview

I have a header view in one of my xib file.I want to reuse this header view in some other views as the header.Can i add this as a subview?Anyone have tried this?I tried with the following code and found not working

```
 claimedPageTemplateone *  claimedtemplateone=[[claimedPageTemplateone alloc]initWithNibName:@"claimedPageTemplateone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
claimedtemplateone.delegate=self;
[ headerView addSubview:claimedtemplateone.background ];
```

where "claimedPageTemplateone" is my view having the header,"background" is synthesized header view which i have to reuse,and "headerView" is the view  where i need to add the subview.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try just to copy your `UIView` from one xib and paste to another xib in Interface Builder.

Comment: All the values in the header should be shown in this view also.So i m looking for a method to reuse that header itself.

Comment: OK, you can't use UIView again, because you can't change its superview. But you can make a deep copy of your UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may work:

```
claimedPageTemplateone *  claimedtemplateone = [[claimedPageTemplateone alloc]initWithNibName:@"claimedPageTemplateone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
claimedtemplateone.delegate=self;

claimedtemplateone.background = [[UIView alloc] initWithNibName:@"background nib name" bundle:[NSBunble mainBundle]];

[ headerView addSubview: claimedtemplateone.background];
```